# CSS3 Transition with Varying Ease Not Working

Tags: html, css

I have tried comparing the code to a few sources, including the tutorial I followed to make it and my transitions aren't working, it's just jumping from its starting state the end with no animation.
Thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="no">no</div>
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div id="two">two</div>
    <div id="three">three</div>
    <div id="four">four</div>
    <div id="five">five</div>
    <div id="minustwo">minustwo</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div {
width: 300px;
margin: 5px 0;
padding: 5px;
color: white;
background-color: #ED8029;
text-align: left;
border-radius: 5px;
}

div:hover  {
width: 700px;
}

div.no {
-webkit-transition: 3s linear;
-moz-transition: 3s linear;
-o-transition:  3s linear;
-ms-transition: 3s linear;
transition: 3s linear 2s;
}

div.one {
-webkit-transition: 3s linear 1s;
-moz-transition: 3s linear 1s;
-o-transition: 3s linear 1s;
-ms-transition: 3s linear 1s;
transition: 3s linear 1s;
}

div.two {
-webkit-transition: 3s linear 2s;
-moz-transition: 3s linear 2s;
-o-transition: 3s linear 2s;
-ms-transition: 3s linear 2s;
transition: 3s linear 2s;
}

div.three {
-webkit-transition: 3s linear 3s;
-moz-transition: 3s linear 3s;
-o-transition: 3s linear 3s;
-ms-transition: 3s linear 3s;
transition: 3s linear 3s;
}

div.four {
-webkit-transition: 3s linear 4s;
-moz-transition: 3s linear 4s;
-o-transition: 3s linear 4s;
-ms-transition: 3s linear 4s;
transition: 3s linear 4s;
}

div.five {
-webkit-transition: 3s linear 5s;
-moz-transition: 3s linear 5s;
-o-transition: 3s linear 5s;
-ms-transition: 3s linear 5s;
transition: 3s linear 5s;
}

div.minustwo {
-webkit-transition: 3s linear -2s;
-moz-transition: 3s linear -2s;
-o-transition: 3s linear -2s;
-ms-transition: 3s linear -2s;
transition: 3s linear -2s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you specify a transition, you need to specify the property you're trying to animate. So, for example, you should write something like:

```
div.no {
-webkit-transition: all 3s linear;
-moz-transition: all 3s linear;
-o-transition: all 3s linear;
-ms-transition: all 3s linear;
transition: all 2s linear;
}
```

[Here's some more info on using transitions.](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp)

Comment: Okay I get it now, in this case you've used `all` to say all properties. You could change that to `width` to just mean a transition on the width. +1

Comment: Yes, you can specify each property individually or you can use all. Using all keeps it short but it may have unintended consequences so it's best to specify each one. I only used all to keep it short.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, so I specified transition width and I'm still not getting the transition just a jump from state to another. Do you know if there is anything that could be blocking it, even though examples I look at, like the one above from W3, transition just fine?

Comment: Ahh, you also need to change the way you're calling the id's. ID's use a '#' sign, the css you wrote is calling classes instead of ID's.